# Django: loading a copy of a model's objects into memory

Tags: python, django, caching

I have a Django project with lots of models, some with many objects and some with few. Several models have a modest number of objects (~100) but are frequently used and infrequently updated. I reference these a lot in my views and so rather than hitting the database to retrieve them I'd like to keep a local copy of them in memory in a dictionary, keyed by primary key. The corresponding table changes so infrequently, I don't mind having to restart my server when I need to update the dictionary.

At the moment I have the line:

```
foo_cache = {foo.pk: foo for foo in Foo.objects.all()}
bar_cache = {bar.pk: bar for bar in Bar.objects.all()}
```

in the various `views.py` files, but I'd like really to import `foo_cache` and `bar_cache` from a separate file, `objects_cache.py` that gets run once and only once when the server starts up. What is the best way to do this? Do I need to create a whole new app, or can I pick one arbitrarily to host the `objects_cache.py` file? Can I or should I do it in `settings.py`?

Comment: Django already does a lot of caching for you transparently. Are you certain that your caching strategy is superior/necessary? Or did you maybe not realize that you get a lot of that for free? Might also be good to look at this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/cache/

Comment: The proper way is to use a proper caching system like `memcached`, but if you have to write it yourself, creating a `CachedModel` mixin would be one of the Pythonic ways.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use the [django-cache-machine](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-cache-machine) or [django-cache-manager](https://github.com/vijaykatam/django-cache-manager).

Cache Machine [is used for](http://jbalogh.me/2010/02/09/cache-machine/) the https://addons.mozilla.org so I suppose that this is a pretty reliable solution.